# bluez version in kubuntu 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04

does anyone know if kubuntu 15.04 will use bluez 5.x? I have a problem with connecting bluetooth audio adapter to my laptop. It might be because Dell, the laptop's manufacturer, doesn't support linux anymore but I'd like to also check if the new version of bluez would help.

Regards,
Artur

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 will use Package: bluez (4.101-0ubuntu22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+source/bluez Ubuntu 15.04 will feature bluez version 4.101 (or one slightly above that, if the devs make another pull from upstream).

Comment: yeah, I actually checked it emporically and installed 15.04 alpha :) Fortunatelly, my bluetooth works better now though still it's not stable

Comment: There's already a first beta release of Vivid btw: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseSchedule